# Is the element accessed as the value of the name attribute of the form element HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection, for-of-loop

```js
for (let i of document.formBox) {
  console.log(i)
};
```

```html
<form name="formBox">
  <input name="inputOne">
  <input name="inputTwo">
  <button name='btn'>BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

The above code works fine. But, is `document.formBox` an `HTMLCollection`? Why can I use a `for..of` statement?

I thought `document.formName` returns `HTMLElement`. However, while accidentally writing that code, I was embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **might** be an element or a collection depending on how many elements have that name.

`for ... of` will work on an element **or** a collection because it cares about the value being iterable, not about it being a collection.

```js
console.log(document.foo.toString());
console.log(document.bar.toString());

for (let x of document.bar) {
    console.log(x.toString());
}
```

```html
<form name="foo"></form>
<form name="foo"></form>

<form name="bar"><input /><input /><input /></form>
```

In the above, `document.foo` is an `HTMLCollection` (containing `HTMLFormElement` instances) because there are multiple forms with the name `"foo"`; you can use `for...of` to loop through the forms in that collection. But `document.bar` isn't an `HTMLCollection` because there's only one form with the name `"bar"`. Instead, it's an `HTMLFormElement`. But `HTMLFormElement` instances are *also* iterable; iterating them loops through the elements in the form.

I strongly recommend avoiding using `document.nameOfElement` as it is ambiguous. Stick to `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` instead.